# How many threads is optimal in this scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I have N cores and cpu-bound work to do (no IO, no blocking calls) which I can split into any number of unrelated chunks then how many threads would be optimal for this? Would it be N?

Comment: Experiment with different values and find out for yourself.

Comment: If you really want to use threads (instead of `Task`s, for example) I'd suggest you use the `ThreadPool`, which manages most of what you're worrying about right now for you.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar So if I were to use `N` threads from `ThreadPool` and then 1000*`N` - iternally it would be the same?

Comment: @ren No, but the thread pool is responsible for creating the optimal number of threads. You could queue 1000 work entries and the thread pool would distribute the work so that the optimal number of threads is busy. Please note that in most cases, the performance-limiting factor is not the number of threads, but the amount of work that can not be performed in parallel (like access to common memory, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal number of threads is equal to the number of hardware threads, which is equal to the number of cores, or the number of cores times two if hyperthreading is enabled.

However, be careful when you say that you "can split [the work] into any number of unrelated chunks". Maybe this is an array of items to process, or something equivalent? If the processing time per item is constant, then you could just statically split the work and assign it to the different threads. However, if different items could take considerable different execution times to process, this strategy may not be optimal. Indeed, it is then quite possible that one thread needs - say - one minute to process 1000 items, while another thread needs an hour to process 1000 different items.

The easiest way is to let the framework handle this for you. Using [`Parralel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) (or a similar method) may be a better idea than creating threads manually.

Answer (score 2):

**It would be `N`.**

The optimal number of threads to use for work is generally the number of cores available to do the work.  This places one thread on each core with no swapping and no idle cores.

There are always exceptions to this rule, based on the specific application and requirements.  But it's a good rule of thumb to start from.